# Mongodb profiler abridging long line and needed information

Tags: mongodb, profiling

I have a query that is run from a python script that looks something like:

`collection.find( {"ID": {"$in": idList } } )`

Where IdList is an array with 20000 or so ids.

My issue is that when I go to look at the profiling data for this query i get output like:

```
{ "ts" : { "$date" : 1396920083560 }, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "allUsers" : [], "user" : "", "err" : "profile line too large (max is 100KB)", "abbreviated" : "{ op: \"query\", ns: \"DB1.players\", query: \"{ ID: { $in: [ 1890, 98437, 117772, 128223, 294193, 255461,...\", ts: new Date(1396920083559), client: \"127.0.0.1\", allUsers: {}, user: \"\" }" }
```

Which seems to skip over the details i want such as 'millis', 'nreturned' and 'nscanned' as my query line is too long.

Is there a way i can retrieve the profiling date i need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [`open defect`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6218) in MongoDB.  I don't think there's any workaround as of today.